# Representing a float as a hexadecimal

Tags: java, floating-point, numbers

I'm studying the float-point type and the examples is a declaration of a variable float expressed as an hexadecimal

float f_in_hex = **Ox1.59a8f6p8f**

This is the computation to find the float value:

(1 * 16^0 + 5 * 16^-1 + 9 * 16^-2 + 10 * 16^-3 + 8 * 16^-4 + 15 * 16^-5 + 6 * 16^-6) * 2^8

So, I know what is the prefix **Ox**, that **base is 16** but I still don't understand why the exponential part start from 0 and goes with negative values

Comment: Try to do your calculation for bigger numbers as well. Try to calculate the value for `0xA1C.59AD` for example, then you'll notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's negative value because it's after the decimal point

16^(-1) is the same as 1/16 = .0625

if it was positive exponent it would be a big number.

hope you understand what i mean

Answer (score -1):

that is not a hexadecimal number, firstly Ox is the letter O and it is not a zero, then within the supposed hexadecimal numbers there is a letter p, the hexadecimal numbers only cover from a-f

Comment: `p` indicates the exponent component of an IEEE 754 encoded float when using hex float literals in Java.